# Troubles with setting up a Build System in Sublime

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, sublimetext, antlr4, build-system

I'm trying to make a Build System for my .g4 files in Sublime Text 3. I've already done alias for antlr4 command in my terminal, and when i'm trying to compile .g4 file from terminal everything works ok. But my current build system in Sublime doesn't ok at all. I'm getting an error `antlr4: command not found`.

```
{
"cmd": ["antlr4", "$file"],
"shell": true
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: here are lines in my .bash_profile

alias antlr4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar'
alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'

Comment: Maybe try `"shell_cmd": "antlr4 \"$file\"",` in place of your `"cmd"` line and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: still "command not found"